# Best way to create dict out of string in Python

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
mystring = "freq1=440,freq2=425,freq3=410,freq4=0,freq5=0,freq6=0,freq7=0,freq8=0,freq9=0,freq10=0,freq11=0,freq12=0,freq13=0,freq14=0,freq15=0,freq16=0"
```

I would like to create a dictionary out of it such that I can access the values like `mydict.freq1`.

I can split the string easily enough:

```
splitstring = mystring.split(',')
```

So I get:

```
freq1=410
freq2=425
freq3=410
freq4=0
```

Which seems far from what I need. Is there an easy way to do this? I am currently on Python 2.7 but working on a migration to 3.0 eventually.

Comment: I can swear I've seen this before, but use `dict(x.split('=') for x in mystring.split(','))`, to split each substring into a pair before converting your sequence of pairs to a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code:

```
dict(x.split('=') for x in my_string.split(','))
```

#### Test Code:

```
my_string = "freq1=440,freq2=425,freq3=410,freq4=0,freq5=0,freq6=0,freq7=0,freq8=0,freq9=0,freq10=0,freq11=0,freq12=0,freq13=0,freq14=0,freq15=0,freq16=0"
my_dict = dict(x.split('=') for x in my_string.split(','))
print(my_dict)
```

#### Results:

```
{'freq1': '440', 'freq2': '425', 'freq3': '410', 'freq4': '0', 'freq5': '0', 'freq6': '0', 'freq7': '0', 'freq8': '0', 'freq9': '0', 'freq10': '0', 'freq11': '0', 'freq12': '0', 'freq13': '0', 'freq14': '0', 'freq15': '0', 'freq16': '0'}
```

Comment: So this worked however if the string has a weird value (e.g. "455,freq1=440,freq=,...") it throws an exception. I changed the code slightly to filter out the empty values: `filter(None, my_string.split(','))` but I don't know how to best deal with the situation where x doesn't include an =. Ideas?

Comment: Error handling is a fine art.  I would likely replace `x.split('=')` with a function to do what ever cleaning was required.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

`mystring = "freq1=440,freq2=425,freq3=410,freq4=0,freq5=0,freq6=0,freq7=0,freq8=0
splitdic={}
for value in mystring.split(','):
    splitdic[value.split("=")[0]]=value.split("=")[1]
print(splitdic)`

**Result:**

`{'freq9': '0', 'freq8': '0', 'freq2': '425', 'freq5': '0', 'freq4': '0', 'freq6': '0', 'freq15': '0', 'freq1': '440', 'freq3': '410', 'freq11': '0', 'freq12': '0', 'freq16': '0', 'freq10': '0', 'freq13': '0', 'freq14': '0', 'freq7': '0'}`

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = "freq1=440,freq2=425,freq3=410,freq4=0,freq5=0,freq6=0,freq7=0,freq8=0,freq9=0,freq10=0,freq11=0,freq12=0,freq13=0,freq14=0,freq15=0,freq16=0"
res= {i.split('=')[0]:i.split('=')[1] for i in mystring.split(',') }

print(res)
```

output

```
{'freq1': '440', 'freq2': '425', 'freq3': '410', 'freq4': '0',
 'freq5': '0', 'freq6': '0', 'freq7': '0', 'freq8': '0', 'freq9': '0',
 'freq10': '0', 'freq11': '0', 'freq12': '0',
 'freq13': '0', 'freq14': '0', 'freq15': '0', 'freq16': '0'}
```